# Can the misspelled [meateorology] tag be deleted?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

[meaterology](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaterology) is obviously a misspelling and so should be deleted (unless *Cloudy with a Chance of Meatballs* actually has a scientific basis ☺) and not made a synonym of the correct spelling.

Comment: I humbly apologise for that tag. I proudly take all responsibility for chuckles that occurred because of it though :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This question](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/posts/70/revisions) was retagged, so the tag will cease to exist at 3:00 UTC. An automated script deletes any "zombie" tags at 3:00 UTC.

Answer (score 1):

The tag is not used by any question now. The system will delete it automatically. The only bad thing that can happen is that someone re-uses it by mistake. Hopefully it won't be the case.

Comment: I've heard of [rains of fish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rain_of_fish). Anyone ever heard of a rain of cows?